# Spring Boot @WebMvcTest having @MockBean null - using SpringRunner works

Tags: spring-boot, junit5

**short:**
there are difficulties in migrating to JUnit5 from Junit4. After removing `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` my `@MockBean` annotated service is null, although I am using `@WebMvcTest'. Why is it not working?

**long:**
I am struggling with that since several days. I am having some tests for my Spring Boot application which worked fine using `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` im combination with `@WebMvcTest`.

Since that is JUnit4 I was trying to migrate to Junit5. I removed the vintage dependecy from the pom and added the exclusion for `spring-boot-starter-test`. There is just the `junit-jupiter` dependency left for JUnit 5.

I read some posts and samples about that. Since I dont want to load the full context, SpringBootTest was not the way (and does not work at all)
I 'think' I found out that `@WebMvcTest` is enough since it already contains the `@extendWith` annotation which is the JUnit5 equivalent for `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)`.
So: I would just have to remove the springRunner and it should work.

But after deleting that single line my with @MockBean annotated service is null from now on.
I can find many samples just using `@WebMvcTest` and `@MockBean`. So I dont understand, why mine is not working.
Adding `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` makes it working again.

Thats the test class (without springrunner):

```java
package my.package;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import my.package.controller.SkillTileCommand;
import my.package.controller.SkillTileController;
import my.package.controller.SkillTileResponse;
import my.package.service.SkillTileService;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockBean;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;

import java.util.List;

import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.hasSize;
import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.any;
import static org.mockito.BDDMockito.given;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.doNothing;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.*;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;

@WebMvcTest(SkillTileController.class)
public class SkillTileControllerIntegrationTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;

    @MockBean
    private SkillTileService skillTileService;

    private final SkillTileTestDataFactory testDataFactory = new SkillTileTestDataFactory();

    @Test
    public void givenSkillTiles_whenGETFindAll_thenReturnJsonArray() throws Exception {

        List<SkillTileResponse> skillTiles = testDataFactory.createTestSkillTileResponses(1, true, null, true);
        SkillTileResponse st1 = skillTiles.get(0);

        given(skillTileService.findAll(null)).willReturn(skillTiles);

        mvc.perform(get("/skill-tile/")
                        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$", hasSize(1)))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].name").value(st1.getName()));
    }
}
```

Instead using Spring runner works like that:

```java
package my.package;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import my.package.controller.SkillTileCommand;
import my.package.controller.SkillTileController;
import my.package.controller.SkillTileResponse;
import my.package.service.SkillTileService;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockBean;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;

import java.util.List;

import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.hasSize;
import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.any;
import static org.mockito.BDDMockito.given;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.doNothing;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.*;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(SkillTileController.class)
public class SkillTileControllerIntegrationTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;

    @MockBean
    private SkillTileService skillTileService;
[...]
}
```

May the head of the service is also of interest:

```java
package my.package.service;

import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import my.package.controller.SkillTileCommand;
import my.package.controller.SkillTileResponse;
import my.package.exception.ResourceNotFoundException;
import my.package.repository.SkillTileEntity;
import my.package.repository.SkillTileRepository;
import my.package.utils.ObjectMapper;
import my.package.utils.ResourceUtility;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Service
public class SkillTileService {

    private final SkillTileRepository skillTileRepository;
[...]
}
```

Here are the both dependencies relating to testing:

```xml
    [...]
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
        <version>5.8.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    [...]
```

Thank you for you help.
It would be nice not to just stay at JUnit4.

Edit:
I also have the same behavior with another testclass which only is annotated with `@DataJpaTest` and having `@Autowire` fields. Their null without the `@RunWith`

Comment: Show your full pom. With spring starter present you cannot override a JUnit dependency just like that.

Comment: Your `@Test` annotation is still from JUnit4 so it will also run with Junit4. Ignoring the `@WebMvcTest` (which includes the JUnit5 annotation) and thus doing nothing with the annotations.

Comment: @M.Deinum god bless you, please make that an answer for honor

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you take a better look at your test you will see that your `@Test` annotation is still from the old `org.junit` package. Which is JUnit4. Which means your test is actually being run with JUnit4 and not JUnit5. Which basically ignores all the annotations and thus also `@WebMvcTest`.

To fix make sure your `@Test` annotations are also from the proper `org.junit.jupiter.api` package to make it a proper JUnit5 test.

Answer (score 1):

There is a possibility that you are using `@RequiredArgsConstructor`in your controller.

Make sure that you have specified the service field as `final`.
The `@RequiredArgsConstructor` documentation states that a constructor will be created with parameters for uninitialized final or @NonNull fields. If SkillTileService dependency was not marked as `final` it's not added as a constructor parameter.

So while the mock itself is not null, it still may be never injected into the tested controller.

Comment: thanks for reply. For me it sounds that you think a mock inside my controller is not set. Thats, i guess, is not the case. Its in my testclass not in the controller class. And its not the controller missing but the service class which is called by that controller. My 'SkillTileController' has '@RequiredArgsConstructor' and 'private final SkillTileService skillTileService;'. My 'SkillTileControllerIntegrationTest' (where the problem occurs) has NOT '@RequiredArgsConstructor' but '@MockBean private final SkillTileService skillTileService;' So? I think thats correct?

Comment: @Kaspatoo, thanks for your clarifications. Yes, seems like I have misunderstood your issue. If something comes to my mind regarding your question, I will post it here.