Dependency not getting mocked in unit test
I am trying to run a unit test for my springboot controller as:
@WebMvcTest(controllers = MyController.class)
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
public class MyControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;

    @MockBean
    private ValidateRequest validateRequest;

    @MockBean
    private MyService myService;

    @Test
    public void createitem_InvalidRequest() throws Exception {
        given(validateRequest.validate(any())).willThrow(new InvalidRequestException("Invalid request"));

        mvc.perform()
        ....
        ....

}

MyController has dependencies ValidateRequest, MyService which are injected at field level using @Autowired.
ValidateRequest is defined as:
@Component
public class ValidateRequest extends SomeBaseClass{
    ....
    ....
}

With this setup, I see that validateRequest is not initialized in test, and is null, thus causing NPE.
Java version is 1.8 and sprinbgoot is 2.3.3.
What am I missing here?
Edited:
junit dependencies are:
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>


Are you trying to create a unit or integration test? Because it looks a hybrid to me

Does it influence the NPE cause?

is ValidateRequest autowired inside of MyController? or where is it used?

another possible issue is if you mistakenly import Junit4 imports, it will ignore @MockMvc and other annotations - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70787407/spring-boot-webmvctest-having-mockbean-null-using-springrunner-works

Yes, ValidateRequest is autorwired inside MyController, using @Autowired.

Do you inject through base class, or through the extended implementation on Controller ? Also does the base class requires any extra state of beans etc ?
